# Dataframe Pandas: make new column by partial string match based on columns of another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have two dataframes

`df1` looks like this (concerned columns):

```
    brand               product_line        size    profile
0   winter              hdw2                21.r    LINEN
1   stone               r294                31x5    WAXY
2   han                 th22                3t      NaN
3   winter              trjj                5t      LINEN
4   stone               ael2                2d      LINEN
```

i have another dataframe that has many columns with concerned columns below:

```
df2
```

```
    NAME                PRODUCT_LINE        SIZE      MAKE 
0   winter+             hdw2                21.r      0.2
1   stoneas             r294                31x5      0.5
2   han                 th22                3t        3
3   winter              trjj                5t        1
4   stone               ael2                2d        34
```

Now basically the columns in first dataframe maps to `NAME`, `PRODUCT_LINE` and `SIZE` respectively. the columns in both dataframes have been `str.lower()` and `str.replace(" ", "")`

Now the I want the `MAKE` column in first dataframe such that this condition should be true for all the rows. I can do it row by row but its taking a lot of time. Is there a way to do it quickly on the entire column without looping through the dataframe? I want an efficient solution.

Below is how I was doing it in loop:

```
spec = df2[(df2['NAME'].str.lower().str.replace(' ', '').str.contains(row.brand.lower().replace(' ', '')))
& (df2['PRODUCT_NAME'].str.lower().str.replace(' ', '').str.contains(row.product_line.lower().replace(' ', ''))) 
& (df2['SIZE'].str.lower().str.replace(' ', '').str.contains(row.size.lower().replace(' ', '')))  ]
```

So basically when the above condition is true for a row, it should then fetch the corresponding MAKE from `df2` and place in `df1`. Also this should only happen when the `profile` column in `df1` is not `NaN`.

Answer (score 0):

To increase efficiency, I'd suggest `merging` the two dataframes horizontally to work on a single dataframe.

Furthermore, since you're only looking to retrieve the MAKE value if all your conditions are met, if one of them isn't, there's no point in comparing the other terms of your observation. This can save you a lot of time.
I therefore introduced a `list_indices` variable which limits the comparison to these values only.

Here is the full code:

```
# imports
import pandas as pd

# Create two DataFrames, df1 and df2, with sample data
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'brand': ["winter", "stone", "han", "winter", "stone"],
    'product_line': ["hdw2", "r294", "th22", "trjj", "ael2"],
    'size': ["21.r", "31x5", "3t", "5t", "2d"],
    'profile': ["LINEN", "WAXY", "NaN", "LINEN", "LiNEN"]
})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'NAME': ["Winter", "stoneas", "han", "winter", "stone"],
    'PRODUCT_LINE': ["hdw2", "r294", "th22", "trjj", "ael2"],
    'SIZE': ["21.r", "31x5", "3t", "5t", "2d"],
    'MAKE': [0.2, 0.5, 3, 1, 34]
})

def clean_columns(df, columns):
    df[columns] = df[columns].applymap(lambda x: str(x).lower().replace(" ", ""))

# List of columns to be cleaned
columns_to_clean_df1 = ['brand', 'product_line', 'size']
columns_to_clean_df2 = ['NAME', 'PRODUCT_LINE', 'SIZE']

# lowercase characters and remove spaces
clean_columns(df1, columns_to_clean_df1)
clean_columns(df2, columns_to_clean_df2)

# Merge the two DataFrames horizontally
df_merged = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)

# Define a list of conditions as pairs of columns to compare
compare_cols = [('brand', 'NAME'), ('product_line', 'PRODUCT_LINE'), ('size', 'SIZE')]

# Initialize a list of row indices where 'profile' is not "NaN"
list_indices = df_merged[df_merged['profile'] != "NaN"].index.tolist()

# Create a new column 'conditions' and set it to False
df_merged['conditions'] = False

# Iterate through each pair of columns in 'conditions'
for col1, col2 in compare_cols:
    # Check if the values in the first column of the pair are present in the second column
    df_merged.loc[list_indices, 'conditions'] = df_merged.iloc[list_indices].apply(lambda row: row[col1] in row[col2], axis=1)

    # Update the list of indices to include only the rows where the condition is satisfied
    # as we only want to retrieve the MAKE column if all conditions have been met, 
    # if one of them hasn't, we stop comparing for this row
    list_indices = df_merged[df_merged['conditions']].index.tolist()
    
# Set the 'MAKE' column to None for rows where conditions are not satisfied
df_merged.loc[~df_merged.index.isin(list_indices), "MAKE"] = None

# Create a new DataFrame 'df_result' with selected columns from df1 and 'MAKE' from df2
df_result = df_merged[df1.columns.tolist() + ["MAKE"]]
```

Here's the result:

|  | brand | product_line | size | profile | MAKE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | winter | hdw2 | 21.r | LINEN | 0.2 |
| 1 | stone | r294 | 31x5 | WAXY | 0.5 |
| 2 | han | th22 | 3t | NaN | NaN |
| 3 | winter | trjj | 5t | LINEN | 1 |
| 4 | stone | ael2 | 2d | LiNEN | 34 |

Let me know if this meets your requirements!